# ERC20: insufficient allowance --> Approve function is not working for depositing ERC-20 tokens in a smart contact

Tags: blockchain, solidity

I'm creating a smart contract to deposit and withdraw USDT token. But I'm getting an error while depositing saying that "ERC20: insufficient allowance".

Below is the solidity function I have used:

```
function depositTokens(uint256 amount, string memory symbol) external {
    ERC20(whitelistedTokens[symbol]).approve(address(this),amount);
    accountBalances[msg.sender][symbol] += amount;
    ERC20(whitelistedTokens[symbol]).transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), amount);
}
```

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l1OHx.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do this in a single transaction. You need 2 transactions for this:

1. The user should first approve the smart contract to transfer USDT token

```
const tx = await USDTToken.approve(userAddress, amount)
await tx.wait()
```

2. Once approved, then call the `USDTToken.depositTokens` function in your solidity contract

```
function depositTokens(uint256 amount, string memory symbol) external {
    accountBalances[msg.sender][symbol] += amount;
    ERC20(whitelistedTokens[symbol]).transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), amount);
}
```

---

This is why, if you have played around with DEXs, you will need two transactions to swap between two tokens:

1. approve
2. transferFrom